# Existe um modo seguro de verificar o carregamento de frames numa página HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frames, iframe

Há algum tempo construí uma ferramenta com HTML e Javascript para auxiliar na depuração de uma família de aplicações web.

Basicamente, a ferramenta consiste numa página HTML estática e uma coleção de scripts que carregam um dado sistema num iframe e então possibilitam inspecionar vários elementos desse sistema, sem que o desenvolvedor precisasse analisar o código-fonte.

Para isso, a ferramenta precisa identificar quando o usuário acessou uma determinada tela para então fazer a inspeção dos elementos.

Porém, os sistemas também usavam frames, às vezes em mais de um nível. Minha solução foi percorrer essa "árvore" de frames adicionando *listeners* para identificar quando cada frame era carregado.

Minha pergunta é: existe uma solução elegante usando jQuery ou javascript para identificar o carregamento de uma hierarquia de frames?

Comment: São `frames` ou `iframes`?

Comment: @mgibsonbr A ferramenta tem um iframe, os sistemas geralmente tem um frameset.

Comment: Para sugerir algo mais elegante, seria bom colocar na pergunta o método actualmente em uso, de forma a inovar ou sugerir algo diferente!

Comment: @Zuul Estou sem meu notebook. Vou postar trechos do código hoje a noite.

Comment: E o tal método em uso? Já é possível colocar o mesmo na pergunta?

Answer (score 3):

> Minha solução foi percorrer essa "árvore" de frames adicionando listeners para identificar quando cada frame era carregado.

Essa é a única solução, não existe mágica ou vodu que verifique de uma vez só se uma hierarquia de objetos `window` ou `document` carregou completamente.

Não conheço os detalhes da sua implementação, mas a solução que imagino ser mais elegante é criar uma função genérica (ou talvez criar um plugin do jQuery) para lidar com isso, utilizando *promises* ou disparando um evento quando tudo estiver carregado. Assim você isola esse problema e não suja sua lógica.

Comment: É possível ver um exemplo junto com a resposta? Na sua forma atual é meramente teórica!